# Using BoundField.DataFormatString to format currency data, no $'s and negative numbers should be in ( )'s

Tags: c#, asp.net, string.format, boundfield

I have a gridview that I am populating with data for the folks in accounting and they want me to format currency values so that they display without $'s, with commas separating digits and with negative numbers surrounded by ( )

e.g.:

12345.67 = 12,345.67 
-12345.67 = (12,345.67)

I have found lots of examples around the interwebs that get me close but there is either no ( ) around negatives or there is a $ included.

Comment: I am trying for a solution that does not put anymore load on the sql server as my query can get fairly complex already and has a tendency to take 40+ seconds to return results in a fairly sparse test system and I am not sure how long it will take once we go live.

Comment: then you should optimize your query, but a simple `case` wouldn't worsen the performance.

Comment: edited my answer and provided a weird way. But i recommend to use RowDataBound because the code will be much more legible. Btw, theres nothing faster than the database.

Comment: @Tim there may not be anything faster that the database but using the data layer to do the work of the presentation layer seems like a road fraught with peril and not a good practice to get into.  Your edited answer does get a lot closer to what I am going for but still isn't quite as concise as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I guess basically the question was, what is the String.Format() call that I would make to format a currency value to the aforementioned requirements.

After messing around with some custom formats I figured it out!

```
var amt = new BoundField ();
amt.DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}";
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Works as a declarative attribute for the asp:BoundField, too!

Answer (score 1):

If it was just numeric without ( ) it would be as simply as {0:N} but since you need ( ) for negative numbers BoundField is not your choice unless you want to do something at sql level or code-behind directly manipulating the datasouce before it is bound to the field.

You next option is to use TemplateField with a Label and set the set accordingly in GV RowDataBound Event in code-behind.